# Getting unusual, possibly malicious prompts when using swirl in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, swirl

After installing swirl and loading it into Rstudio I received this message:

```
Do you want to set the language to Chinese traditional?(y/n)
```

When I say no I then get this:

```
| Welcome to swirl! Please select where you want to sign in with.

1: Google 2: Facebook 3: Classroom
```

After logging in via google (I got redirected to what seemed to be a genuine google login page, with my various google accounts pre-loaded, I just had to pick one) and loading a course, the text is all in chinese anyway.

I found a couple of other people with this problem but no answer as to how it happens.

https://github.com/swirldev/swirl/issues/666

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swirl-discuss/gB0vDmCIJWA

I'm running Rstudio on a Mac.

Any clues?

Comment: Happened to me after installing the Chinese course https://swirlstats.com/scn/dsandr.html Everything was fine before. I cannot uninstall this particular one so far and cannot get back to main menu.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I could neither uninstall this particular course, nor all of them (`uninstall_all_courses(force = TRUE)`), and not even remove the package (`remove.packages("swirl")`). I just re-installed `swirl`, that did the job. Load courses again. Try

```
install.packages("swirl")
```

Best regards